# JointJS event handler in typescript

Tags: typescript, jointjs

I'm trying to add event handler for jointjs paper in typescript,But don't found a way to implement it with joint js definition file.

```
private paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
          el: $('#paper'),
          width: 650,
          height: 400,
          gridSize: 20,
          model: this.graph,
          markAvailable: true,
          linkConnectionPoint: joint.util.shapePerimeterConnectionPoint,
          snapLinks: true
     });

   this.paper.on('mouseclick', () => {
      console.log('Congratulations, you clicked the mouse!');
   });
```

get error message

TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

How to add event handler for rect and lines with typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works with me

```
   paper.on('cell:pointerup', () => {
      console.log('Congratulations, you clicked the mouse!');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

JointJS leans heavily on other libraries, such as jQuery and Backbone. In this case, the paper.mouseclick() function allows you to pass in an Event should according to the the **joint.d.ts** definition file:

```js
mouseclick(evt: Event): void;
```

Calling this, with an Event as parameter, will trigger the event. However, I assume you're actually more interested on handling the event rather than triggering it. In this case, the Paper class extens a Backbone.View where you can act on it as follows:

```js
let paper = new jointjs.dia.Paper();
paper.on('mouseclick', () => {
  console.log('Congratulations, you clicked the mouse!');
});
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for you concern I have tried your code but I get new error,I have updated question

Answer (score 0):

I have this one working for me:

```
paper.on('blank:pointerclick', function(evt, x, y) {

  //do whatever

}); //end paper.on
```